# Task.Factory.StartNew() not firing the ElapsedEventHandler event

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In my following code, the Timer_Elapsed event is not hitting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Logger
{
    internal class Country
    {       
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
    internal class CountryLogger
    {
        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>()
        {
            new Country{CountryName = "India", CountryCode="IND"},
            new Country{CountryName = "United States of America",  CountryCode="USA"},
            new Country{CountryName = "United Kingdom", CountryCode="UK"},
            new Country{CountryName = "Australia", CountryCode="AUS"}
        };
        public void WriteToLog()
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\ParallelLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            {
                foreach (Country Country in countries.AsParallel().AsOrdered())
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", Country.CountryName, Country.Count  ryCode);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 3 * 60 * 1000;  
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);                                      
        }
        static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           //{
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                CountryLogger countriesLogger = new CountryLogger();
                countriesLogger.WriteToLog();
            });
            //}
        }
    }    
}
```

Also the **Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>** object is not looping through the for loop (Commented because it doesn't work).

Can someone suggest the better way of writing this code to work?!

Comment: `Main` exits, program ends, timers are torn down.

Answer (score 1):

What should the first program thread do whilst letting the timer run?

Here, I'm just waiting for the user to hit return:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 3 * 60 * 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        GC.KeepAlive(timer); //Can't decide if this is needed or not
    }
```

What *is* important is that if you `return` from `Main` (or just hit that final `}`), your program is going to exit. I can't remember whether timers keep themselves alive in terms of Garbage Collection, so I've added a `GC.KeepAlive` just in case.

---

I've also switched around the order of assignments on the timer - so that it's not *enabled* until I know that the handler is attached and that the interval is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Damien! So how about the Windows Service scenario? I am going to have Timer implementation in my windows service OnStart(). I will not be able to accomodate Console.ReadLine(). Please suggest!

Comment: @SriramB - in a service, you tend to need to have at least one non-background thread running - you might just start a new thread that just `Wait`s on a `ManualResetEvent` that you `Set` in your `OnStop` method - unless or until you find some useful work for that thread to do.